# How to retrieve all comments for a particular ad in facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, ads

[this is an Graph API call to retreive information about the ad, what should I additionally type in order to seel all comments associated with this ad?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhyu3.png)

I tried some videos, chatGPT, read through the Facebook documentation. But still can't find the solution.
I want to know what API call (using GraphAPI) should I do in order to retreive and delete information about comments that are related to ads.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.